# Method decorator which modifies class ?

Tags: typescript

Might it be possible to develop a method decorator, ie: "@rpcMethod" which 
modifies a class's prototype ?

At the end I want:

```
@rpcMethod
get(){
   ....
}
```

and at run-time:

```
instance.getRpcMethods(); //returns ['get']
```

I tried all sort of things inside the decorator (ie:modify target.prototype) but it all failed.

thanks!

Comment: Do you know that you can use a class decorator?

Comment: yes, but yet i don't know how to collect all methods decorated with '@rpcMethod' at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late reply, try this:

```
var rpcMethod = (target: Object, propName: string, propertyDescriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<() => any>) => {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, "getRpcMethods");
    if (desc.configurable)
    {
        Object.defineProperty(target, "getRpcMethods", { value: function() { return this["rpcMethods"]; }, configurable: false });
        Object.defineProperty(target, "rpcMethods", { value: [] });
    }

    target["rpcMethods"].push(propName);
};


class MyClass
{
    public getRpcMethods():string[] {
        throw new Error("Should be implemented by decorator");
    }

    @rpcMethod
    public get() {
        return "x";
    }

    @rpcMethod
    public post() {
        return "y";
    }
}

var myInstance = new MyClass();

myInstance.getRpcMethods();
```

Comment: hey, fantastic! Thank you so much.